# Use C# to duplicate a chart in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I've got a spreadsheet that contains a template chart. In the past I've used the copy/paste functionality, but from time to time I run into an error where I copy something onto the clipboard at the same time my code is and I'd like to avoid that. So I looked into the Duplicate method. Should the code below work? The chart does get duplicated fine.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to get the chart object after it has been duplicated. On this line:

```
ChartObject chart = (ChartObject)o;
```

I get this error: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject'. Here is my code:

```
string file = @"D:\test.xlsx";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
ApplicationClass temp = new ApplicationClass();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

oBook = app.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, false, 1, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, true, XlCorruptLoad.xlNormalLoad);
oSheet = oBook.Worksheets["template"] as Worksheet;

object o = ((ChartObject)oSheet.ChartObjects("template")).Duplicate();
ChartObject chart = (ChartObject)o;
chart.Name = "TEST";
```

Can I get the count of ChartObjects? If I were doing it in a macro I could use this line to get the last chart

```
oSheet.ChartObjects(oSheet.ChartObjects.Count)
```

Any suggestions? I sincerely appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Nick

In the event anyone is interested in how I ended up doing this. Assuming you have a worksheet named "template" and on that sheet you also have a chart named "template."

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oTemplate = oBook.Worksheets["template"] as Worksheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oOutput = oBook.Worksheets["output"] as Worksheet;

// duplicate template chart
ChartObject chartTemplate = (ChartObject)oTemplate.ChartObjects("template");
object o = chartTemplate.Duplicate();
ChartObject chart = (ChartObject)oTemplate.ChartObjects(GetChartCount(oTemplate));

public static int GetChartCount(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet)
{
    int x = 0;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape s in oSheet.Shapes)
    {
        if (s.HasChart == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            x++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Maybe not the best way, but it works.

Comment: When duplicating a chartobject the return type seems to be "Shape": if you can't cast that to a chartobject then maybe you could try something like  `ChartObject chart = (ChartObject)oSheet.ChartObjects(o.Name);`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm cheating now and added a foreach to loop through each shape. Then I check to see if it's a chart. Then I use that number to get the last one. I'll try your suggestion too. Thanks again.